# Rails. Inject user objects into message objects on output

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am developing an Rails 3 API and in this API I got tables called users, messages and contacts. The contact table consists of two main fields (user_id and friend_id). The message table consists of two main columns (user_id, message)

I want to get all the messages that belongs to the users contacts. This works fine using the code below. What I need is to include the user data into each message output aswell.

This is my code in the message controller:

```
def profile_updates
  @contacts = current_user.contacts
  @messages = Array.new
  @contacts.each do |contact|
    user = User.find(contact.friend_id)
    user.messages.each do |message|
      @messages << message
    end
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :text => 'Use either JSON or XML' }
    format.json { render :json => @messages}
    format.xml { render :xml => @messages}
  end
end
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that a message belongs_to a user, you should just be able to do this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render :text => 'Use either JSON or XML' }
  format.json { render :json => @messages.to_json(:include => :user) }
  format.xml { render :xml => @messages.to_json(:include => :user) }
end
```

To only include specific User fields, you may want to define a custom method:

```
class Message
  def user_info
    {:first_name => user.first_name, :last_name => user.last_name}
  end
end

respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render :text => 'Use either JSON or XML' }
  format.json { render :json => @messages.to_json(:methods => :user_info) }
  format.xml { render :xml => @messages.to_json(:methods => :user_info) }
end
```

Comment: Thank worked beautifully, thanks! There is only one small problem. I only want to return the firstname and the lastname of the user. Now I also get the password, email and so on. How can I do that?